# How can I get friend's activity streams and public activities from myspace using C#?

Tags: c#, myspace

I am developing an ASP application for myspace. I want to get the friend's activity streams and all of their updates.

How would I get started with this in C#?

Comment: Can you please tell us what you have tried, and how it fails? Then we can give you more specific advice.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the endpoint to get Activities (both you and your friends): http://wiki.developer.myspace.com/index.php?title=OpenSocial_v0.9_Activities

If you would like Public Activities, check out the Real-Time PUSH subscription feature: http://wiki.developer.myspace.com/index.php?title=Category:Real_Time_Stream

To get started using the MySpace APIs with C#, check out the C# SDK: http://wiki.developer.myspace.com/index.php?title=Category:MySpaceID_SDK_for_C_Sharp